# Robotium - Task 'androidTest' not found in project ':APPName'

Tags: java, android, gradle, robotium

I'm using robotium to make a small test for an app and I receive the next error when running "./gradlew androidTest" :Task 'androidTest' not found in project ':APPName'.

I have the next structure:
--src
---main
----androidTest
-----java
------test.java (e.g.)

My gradle file contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
        }

        release {
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The androidTest folder must be a child of src.

```
- project
-- src
--- androidTest
--- main
```